# Display parent navigation doesn't work

Tags: navigation, site

We have a SharePoint 2010 site that has a subsite which then contains a subsite. It looks something like this hierarchically:

```
- Site Root
  - Subsite A
     - Subsite X (subsite of A)
     - Subsite Y (subsite of A)
```

Is there a way to have the subsites A, X, and Y all show the same navigation in the Quick Launch area as Site Root? I've tried "Display the same navigation items as the parent site" in the various sites' Site Actions > Site Settings > Navigation. However, that causes the sites to show a blank Quick Launch.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

**Update:** Found somewhat of an answer, though I'm not sure why SharePoint behaves this way: If we have a parent site and any number of child sites, to get the children to show the parent navigation, this is what we need to do:

1. On the parent site, go to Site Actions > Site Settings > Navigation.
2. Select "Display only the navigation items below the current site" along with "Show subsites" and "Show pages."
3. In the child site, go to Site Actions > Site Settings > Navigation.
4. Select "Display the same navigation items as the parent site."

If on the parent site you choose "Display the same navigation items as the parent site", the child won't show the correct navigation. In our case, it showed nothing at all!

If anyone can shed some light on why it behaves this way, that would be great.

Comment: Well it sounds like the parent site needs to be told what to display directly, and the child sites merely inherit that from the parent. Expected behaviour, really.

Comment: Thanks, James. Being relatively new to SP2010 (4 months), I was still trying to understand the navigational aspects :)

Comment: Ah no worries. Yeah, 'display same as parent' essentially means 'use the same settings as parent', in other words it just inherits the settings. Think it's the only component that uses that wording instead of 'inherits', like everything else does in SharePoint.